# One Sample T-Test - Data Transformation

Tags: t-test, lognormal-distribution

I apologize in advance is this question seems very elementary. It has been a long time since I have dabbled in significance tests and I can't seem to find an answer to this anywhere else.

I have a dataset (n=52) of samples that I would like to test against a known value (e.g., 5). Because, I am testing my population mean against a known mean, this would be a one-sample t-test. Please correct me if I'm wrong. My data is positively skewed (majority of samples are low, with some high outliers) and I understand that a normal distribution is necessary to support the use of a parametric test.

I suppose I have two questions:

1. When I log transform my data, the histogram, Q-Q plot, kurtosis, skew, etc. all strongly suggest the data is normal enough for a t-test. From here, do I also log transform the known mean I am testing against (e.g., log10(5))?
2. Is something like this typically done for a one-sample t-test or should I try a non-parametric test?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the estimator of a funtion of the parameter (log in this case) is the function of the estimator not the function of the data. If T is an estimator of mu, f(T) is an estimator of f(mu). So, the log of the data do not estimate the log of the mean.

Comment: @BruceET Part 2 is not a yes or no question! (or, rather is the conjunction of two yes or no questions :). Does "no" apply to the part about "typically done for one-sample t tests" or to the part about "try a non-parametric test"?

Comment: @Alexis. The main difficulty (as the question now stands) is with the null value $\log_{10}5.$ But (depending on the meaning of "something like this"), I object to Part 2 altogether. The natural log of a lognormal will be normal and a correctly formulated t test would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Preliminaries.** You might want to start by reviewing the standard definition of
the lognormal distribution and fundamental facts about its mean and variance, either in a textbook or on the
relevant [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution).

Three points are of particular importance for your question.

(1) If you take the natural log $(\log_e=\ln,$ *not* $\log_{10})$ of lognormal
data, then you get data from the corresponding normal distribution.

(2) If the mean and SD of the normal population are $\mu$ and $\sigma,$ respectively, then
the mean of the lognormal population will be $\exp(\mu+\sigma^2/2).$

(3) Because the relationship between
the mean and variance of normal and corresponding lognormal
distributions is not trivial, it is customary (but sometimes possibly confusing) to use
the normal *parameters* for the corresponding *lognormal* distribution.

Demo with huge lognormal sample in R for $\mu=5, \sigma=1,$ for which sample mean nearly matches population mean:

```
set.seed(1234)
mean(rlnorm(10^7, 5, 1))
[1] 244.775
exp(5 + .5)
[1] 244.6919
```

**Fictitious data for illustration.** Consider fictitious normal data `y` and corresponding
lognormal data `x` as follows:

```
set.seed(2021)
y = rnorm(52, 5, 1)   # normal
x = exp(y)            # lognormal

# Normal
summary(y);  length(y);  sd(y)  
    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  2.744   4.023   4.990   4.962   5.902   7.120 
[1] 52        # sample size
[1] 1.156031  # sample SD
shapiro.test(y)$p.val
[1] 0.177547           # not signif different from normal

# Lognormal
summary(x);  length(x);  sd(x)
  Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 15.55   55.95  146.93  257.55  365.94 1236.45 
[1] 52
[1] 278.6784
shapiro.test(x)$p.val
[1] 3.559653e-07      # normality strongly rejected
```

The normal sample `y` (left panel) has a normal probability plot that is roughly linear, except possibly for a few points in the tails. The red reference line goes through the theoretical
and sample upper and lower quartiles. Lognormal sample `y` (right panel) is clearly not normal.

[image]

R code for figure:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 qqnorm(y, main="Normal QQ Plot: Normal")
  qqline(y, col="red")
 qqnorm(x, main="Normal QQ Plot: Lognormal")
  qqline(x, col="red")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

**one-sample t test on normal data.** You could do a one sample t test on the normal data `y`,
as you suggest. Because these are fictitious data sampled
with mean $\mu_y = 5,$ the null hypothesis $H_0: \mu_y = 5$
is not rejected in favor of the alternative $H_a: \mu_y \ne 5.$

```
t.test(y, mu=5)

        One Sample t-test

data:  y
t = -0.2354, df = 51, p-value = 0.8148
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 5
95 percent confidence interval:
 4.640422 5.284104
sample estimates:
mean of x              # output uses symbol 'x'
 4.962263 
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 257.5527
```

However, $\mu_x = E(X) = 244.6919,$ the *lognormal* mean,
has natural log about $5.2,$ which is **not** $E(Y),$ so $H_0: \mu_y = 5.2$ is
strongly rejected in favor of $H_a: \mu_y \ne 5.2$
with P-value far below 5%.

```
t.test(y, mu=5.5)$p.val
[1] 0.001507389
```

Comment: Thanks to @Luke for attempted edit. Just got out of "minor surgery" so making even more typos than usual. Hope I have found all the typos now.

Comment: thank you for the detailed response. I'm not sure that I entirely follow as this is a bit out of my scope. I'm still a bit unsure how to proceed but I'll keep looking into it.

Comment: Can you say what is the _first_ part of the answer you don't 'entirely follow'? One key point is that you can't take the $\ln$ of lognormal mean to get corresp. normal mean. (That works for _medians,_ but not for means.)

Comment: I can back up a little with my question and see if that helps as well. I have seen a few examples and videos on transforming data prior to running a two-sample T-test, and the data transformation must be applied to both datasets (otherwise you would be testing if the mean of variance 1 is equal to the transformed mean of variance 2).

Comment: Because I would like to run a one-sample T-test, however, and my data (untransformed) is not normally distributed, I am unsure how to proceed. Transforming the data does improve the normality so I am wondering if I apply the same logic as the two-sample T-test, which would be to transform both my data AND transform the known value I would like to test against. Or do I leave the known value I am testing against untransformed? Does this help?

Comment: It is a fine idea to take the natural log of lognormal data so that you can do a t test. You just have to figure out what the normal mean for the null hypothesis is. // For a _linear_ transformation you have $E(aX+b) = aE(X) + b,$ but it's more complicated for a non-linear transformation.